# Idioma del corrector ortográfico de Microsoft Word

Tags: php, laravel-5, phpword

En mi proyecto he incluido la opción de imprimir en Word. Para ello, tengo este código:

```
public function imprimirWord(Juego $j){
    $phpWord=new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();
    $section=$phpWord->addSection();

    $text=$section->addText('Juego Nº '.$j->numero.': '.$j->nombre,array('name'=>'Arial','size' => 15,'bold' => true));
    $text=$section->addText("-Materiales requeridos: ".$j->materiales);
    $text=$section->addText("-Agrupación: ".$j->organizacion);
    $text=$section->addText("-Cómo se organiza el juego: ".$j->agrupacion->nombre);
    $text=$section->addText("-Desarrollo del juego: ".$j->desarrollo);
    if($j->observaciones!='*')
        $text=$section->addText("-Reglas y observaciones: ".$j->observaciones);
    if($j->variantes!='*')
        $text=$section->addText("-Variantes del juego: ".$j->variantes);
    $contenidos=$j->enlaces;
    $valor=count($contenidos);
    if($valor){
        $texto="";
        foreach($contenidos as $contenido){
            $texto.=" ".$contenido->contenido->nombre;
            $valor--;
            if($valor>1)
                $texto.=",";
            else if($valor==1)
                $texto.=" y";
            else
                $texto.=".";
        }
        $text=$section->addText("-Contenidos del juego:".$texto);
    }

    $objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'Word2007');
    $objWriter->save('Prueba.docx');
    return response()->download(public_path('Prueba.docx'));
}
```

Y al ejecutarlo obtengo esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y aquí esta mi problema: Una vez el documento se imprime, el idioma del autocorrector se pone en inglés en lugar de en español.

Lo puedo modificar, pero no es deseable tener que estar yendo a cambiar el idioma cada vez que se imprima un nuevo fichero. ¿Cómo lo arreglo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En la sección [3.3.6 de la documentación de PHPWord](https://phpword.readthedocs.io/en/latest/general.html#document-language) (aquí en [PDF](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/phpword/latest/phpword.pdf)) se indica cómo definir el lenguaje que se va a utilizar en el texto (traducción mía):

> #### 3.3.6 Idioma del documento
>
> El idioma por defecto del documento puede cambiarse con el siguiente códiog:
>
> ```
> $phpWord->getSettings()->setThemeFontLang(new Language(Language::FR_BE));
> ```
>
> `Language` tiene tres parámetros, uno para los idiomas latinos, otro para los idiomas del Este Asiático y otro para idiomas complejos (bidireccionales). Un par de códigos de lenguaje se encuentran en la clase `PhpOffice\PhpWord\ComplexType\Language` pero cualquier código/ID válido puede ser usado.
>
> En caso de estar generando un documento RTF, el idioma se especifica de forma diferente:
>
> ```
> $lang = new Language();
> $lang->setLangId(Language::EN_GB_ID);
> $phpWord->getSettings()->setThemeFontLang($lang);
> ```

---

Entones, en tu caso que es un documento de Word 2007, para especificar que es español, deberías usar algo como esto:

```
$phpWord->getSettings()->setThemeFontLang(new Language(Language::ES_ES));
```

Comment: Puedes encontrar una lista de idiomas que tienen su propio valor predefinido en el código de PHPWord, en el fichero [`PHPWord/src/PhpWord/Style/Language.php`](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/blob/fe454dbaf31111dff69886ab600f99ff99033cd4/src/PhpWord/Style/Language.php) (lo pongo como referencia porque, aunque ES_ES está definido como _constante_, otros locales no lo están).

Comment: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Language' not found. ¿Que deberia importar con "use"?

Comment: @MiguelAlparez Prueba indicando la clase como `PhpOffice\PhpWord\Style\Language()`

Comment: Los parentesis de Language sobran, pero al usar "PhpOffice\PhpWord\Style\Language" he logrado que funcione. ¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: Genial. Me alegro que te sirviera de ayuda :)

Comment: saben como poner en "Español-Mexico"???